# Flex WebService invokeAllPending never called

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I been using the WebService and Operation classes of Flex Framework for a while, and after some ups and downs (more downs than ups, haha) I'm in process of refactoring all its uses with some utility classes/wrappers.

After browsing a little of the code of mx.rpc.soap.Operation I noticed that when you use the method "send" and the web service is not ready then the call is queued to an internal array (pendingInvocations:Array in line 1142). But the funny thing is that the invocations in the queue are never called again.

This is a bug or there is something I'm doing wrong?

I'm considering extending mx.rpc.soap.Operation, overriding "send" and testing if there are invocation queued, calling invokeAllPending (a mx_internal method that pops all the queued invocations) my self.

But the other problem is that that method is mx_internal, so I don't know if Adobe is gonna change it any time soon.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug.  Take a look at the definition for `AbstractWebService`; it defines a method called `unEnqueueCalls` (which is right up near the top of the list of awkward method names that I've seen :)).  This method loops through all the operations in the webservice and invokes the pending calls for each operation by calling that `invokeAllPending` method you found.

`unEnqueueCalls` is itself called from the `WebService` class, in the `wsdlFault` and `wsdlHandler` methods, one of which runs when your WSDL is finished loading.

So, everything is all accounted for; you don't need to override anything.